# В конечном результате не выводятся методы по решению задания в тестовом классе `Main`

Tags: java

Всем здравия, столкнулся с проблемой, что все методы в классах описал и в конечном тестовом классе `Main` прошу на вывод результаты из класса `Action`, но к сожалению ничего не выводит.

Помогите пожалуйста понять, в чём заключается моя ошибка? Сам же я думаю, что вся проблема в классе Action, но где именно не нашёл.

Заранее спасибо!

Вот сам код:

Пакет test, класс Main

```
package test;
import action.Action;
import factory.Factory;

public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    String [] str = new String[1];
    Factory.symbols(str);
    String regex = "\\b\\w*(\\w)\\1\\w*\\b";
    System.out.println("1) Удалите с помощью регулярного выражения все слова из предложения, содержащие две одинаковые следующие друг за другом буквы");
    
    for(String s : str) {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(s);
        Action.symbolsMatches(regex, sb);
    }
   
    Factory.tender(str);
    System.out.println("2) Подсчитать суммы кодов символов лексем во введенном предложении и проверить, является ли полученный числовой ряд невозрастающей последовательностью. ");
    Action.codesSum();
}
}
```

Пакет action, класс Action

```
package action;

import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;

public class Action {
    
static public void symbolsMatches(String regex, StringBuffer symbols) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(symbols);
    while(matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(symbols.toString().replaceAll(regex, "") + matcher.group());
        }

}


static public void codesSum () {
    
    String tender = "";
    String[] words = tender.split(" ");
    int prevSum = -1;
    
    for(String word : words) {
       int sum = 0;     
       for(char ch : word.toCharArray()) {
           sum += (int) ch;
        }
    if (prevSum != -1){
        if (prevSum < sum){
            
            return;
        }
    prevSum = sum;

    }
System.out.println(tender);
        }
}

}
```

Пакет interface, interface IF

```
package interfaces;

public interface IF {
String symbols[] = {"В настоящее время действует ограничение проверок для незарегистрированных пользователей"
};
String tender[] = {"admin coming home"};
}
```

Пакет factory, класс Factory

```
package factory;
import interfaces.IF;
public class Factory implements IF{
 
    static public void symbols(String str[]) {
        for(int i = 0; i < symbols.length; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < str.length; j++) {
                str[i] = symbols[i];
            }
        }
    }
    static public void tender(String str[]) {
        for(int i = 0; i < tender.length; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < str.length; j++) {
                str[i] = tender[i];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: у вас регулярное выражение не отрабатывает. но я бы на вашем месте забыл про него и попробовал изучить прописные истины, потому как настолько неопревданно сложного кода я в своей жизни, пожалуй, не видел (а я работал с индусами и африканцами!). вы когда нибудь слышали про принцип kiss? так вот у вас antikiss. вы не знаете, что такое интерфейс, не понимаете , что такое фабрика. зачем вам сейчас регулярка?? займитесь изучением более полезного материала

Comment: @Дмитрий да я бы с радостью изучил то, что мне необходимо, но образовательная программа такая, у нас начальное изучение джавы, а мы нам уже регулярные выражения и фабрику пихают...
Про прописные истины я изучу обязательно, но всё же код нужно доделать.
Можете пожалуйста указать на мои ошибки, просто interface и factory работать должны, мне так учитель сказал, да и регулярка должна своё отрабатывать...Проверял на 101regex

Comment: Да, и я знаю, что данный код можно уменьшить в разы, но пока что делаю, что говорят.
Так вот, как мне сделать, чтобы он отрабатывал, просто у меня с самого изучения с `Main` ссоры(

Comment: @Дмитрий , возможно такое, что одна из проблем заключается в кириллице?



P.S. Есть есть ещё вот такая регулярка, если всё же дело в ней, `(\w)\1`, она проверяет два одинаковых следующих друг за другом символа, но в задании мне необходимо делитнуть полностью слово, которое как раз таки и может состоять из этих символов.

Comment: @Дмитрий так же вот `\b\w*(\w)\1\w*\b` , но в самом компиляторе данная запись выводит ошибку: `Недопустимая escape-последовательность (допустимы только \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ )` .